# Handsontable - Metadata definition object

Tags: merge, save, metadata, state, handsontable

In [Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/), it is possible to get data object via getData function.
I also need to save metadata of Handsontable instance e.g. actual column sizes, merged cells etc.
Is it possible to get one object which describes actual state of table and use it to save and load state along with data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a custom renderer you could build this object each time the table gets rendered (which happens quite often). What I would do is create this global object, call it `metaData`, with the keys you need (`columnSizes`, `mergedCells`, etc), and as the renderer goes through, store this data. What I mean by "as the renderer goes through" is that the custom renderer, if set for each column, will get called for each cell, or `td` tag. What you'd then do is use the information given which includes this tag, row/col indeces, values, instance, etc.

I say use the custom rendering because the sort of meta data you mention seems to all be related to the rendering and not the actual data. Would this work for you? It's the best way I can think of doing this.

Comment: I found out that in my case I need 4 objects to store complete state of the table: column widths, row heights, mergedCells and  data

With these I was able to construct options object and rebuild HOT with these options. Your answer helped me to figure out what I need to store. Thanks.

Comment: Could you add an example for colomn widths? Or give some links where to read about creating custom renderers?